# MVC Regex model validation

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, validation, model-view-controller, model

I want to have at least 3 numbers in my password.
This validation always fails :

```
 [RegularExpression(@"[\d]{3}", ErrorMessage ="Password must have at least 3 digits")]
        [Display(Name = "NewPassword", ResourceType = typeof(ModelResources))]
        public string NewPassword { get; set; }
```

I have also tried with () in the expression. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Something like `\d.*?\d.*?\d` maybe.

Comment: Still fails... Thank you for your answer. :)

Comment: Try `^.*?\d.*?\d.*?\d.*?$`

Comment: Try `"^([^0-9]*[0-9]){3}.*$"` - this must require at least three digits

Comment: @stribizhev - why didn't you use the digit class `\d` ?

Comment: @sln: I explained it in my answer below. There is a difference between `\d` and `[0-9]` in .NET regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To require at least three digits, you may use

```
"^([^0-9]*[0-9]){3}.*$"
```

or

```
@"^(?:\D*\d){3}.*$"
```

or the least effecient regex:

```
^(.*\d){3}.*$
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%3F%3A%5CD*%5Cd)%7B3%7D.*%24&i=av12c3)

Note that in .NET `\d` matches more than just `[0-9]` digits, it can match Arabic and other digits. The `[^0-9]` and `\D` matches any character but a digit.

- `^` - start of string
- `([^0-9]*[0-9]){3}` - exactly 3 occurrences of 0 or more sequences of

  - `[^0-9]*` (or `\D*`) 0 or more characters other than a digit
  - `[0-9]` (or `\d`) - a digit
- `.*` - 0 or more characters other than a newline
- `$` - end of string

Please note that using opposite character classes to match 3 digits follows the [principle of contrast](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast), which is very effecient compared to dot matching as it involves much less backtracking. You can check for yourself at regex101.com at *regex debugger* section: it takes 2 backtracking steps for [my regex](https://regex101.com/r/sO5pI1/1) to complete matching and it takes [`^(.*\d){3}.*$`](https://regex101.com/r/sO5pI1/3) ~180 steps to complete matching in the same string.

Comment: This regex matches *exactly* 3 digits, not "at least 3 digits".

Comment: It matches 3 digits *obligatorily* and then *any* number (`*`) of *any* (`.`) characters. The 3 digit matching part (`(?:\D*\d){3}`) is based on [*contrast principle*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast) and is much more effecient than `(.*\d){3}` since it involves less backtracking. If you cannot support your downvote with hard facts, why lose reputation points?

Comment: I will agree with you that your longer regex should be used where performance of executed code is the highest priority. When it comes to regex's, I tend to favor human readability over performance, all other factors notwithstanding.

Comment: @AlanMcBee: When you deal with regexes, performance should always be taken into account.

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization: "For those who don't work to strict memory or CPU cycle limits, PrematureOptimization is an AntiPattern, ..."